# git add file to archive

Tags: git, github, gitignore, gitattributes

When I run this command, the files of my latest commit are **saved to a ZIP**.

```
git archive -o ../code_version0.9.zip HEAD
```

However **the files** in `node_modules` and `build/` **are missing.**

That Is because my `.gitignore` is the following one:

```
node_modules
build/
```

**How can I ignore files, but Include them In the archive?** 
I looked into the documentation for `.gitattributes` but I couldn't find a include statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my knowledge goes, `git archive` only archives files *tracked* by git, and `.gitignore` only ignores *untracked* files. Hence you will never manage to `git archive` files that are in your `.gitignore`. Or what am I missing?